# OpenLayers 3, PostgreSQL, WFS: Extent jumps back to initial extent if zoom out too far

Tags: postgis, openlayers, wfs, extents, zoom

I'm working on an app using OpenLayers 3 with PostgreSQL/PostGIS tables and views, and an Esri basemap.

The web app loads a set of features using an array of attributes from PostGres table (a view) and a cql filter. then zooms to the extent of the collected features.
All this works as expected.  The problem happens when I zoom out after the features are loaded...if I zoom out more than a few levels, the extent suddenly jumps back to the initial extent of the features when loaded.

Here is (what I think is) the relevant code below... I am not getting any errors in console; the fetching and loading of the features looks ok from what I can see.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
      url: 'http://server:6080/arcgis/rest/services/basemap/MapServer',
  })
})
],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat]),
    minZoom: 11,
    zoom: 15,
    maxZoom: 20
  })
});
```

...

```
var locExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          loader: function (extent) {
              $.ajax('http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: {
                      service: 'WFS',
                      version: '1.1.0',
                      request: 'GetFeature',
                      typename: 'all_features_search',
                      srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                      outputFormat: 'application/json',
                      CQL_FILTER: "attribute IN " + tostring
                  }
              }).done(function (response) {
                  layerWFS
                  .getSource()
                  .addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                  .readFeatures(response));
                  layerWFS.set('name', 'search_layer');
                  //
                  var radius = 100;
                  var  locExtent = layerWFS.getSource().getExtent();
                  locExtent = ol.extent.buffer(locExtent, radius);
                  ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'), ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'));
                  map.getView().fit(locExtent, map.getSize());
                  var theseFeatures = layerWFS.getSource().getFeatures();
                  for (var i = 0; i < theseFeatures.length; i++) {
                    var featureWKT = theseFeatures[i].get('wkt');
                    var featureType = 
                    featureWKT.substr(0,featureWKT.indexOf('('));
                    // there are both point and line features in view
                    if (featureType == "POINT"){
                      theseFeatures[i].setStyle(pointStyle);
                    } else { // MULTILINESTRING
                      theseFeatures[i].setStyle(lineStyle);
                    }

                  }
              });
          },
          strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
          projection: 'EPSG:3857',
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',

      })
    });

  map.addLayer(layerWFS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the good people at Boundless helped me find the solution:

I changed
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox

to 
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all